# HP DL380 G3 and Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, hp, ubuntu-12.04, hp-proliant

I have bought a **HP Proliant DL380 G3** and am attempting to install **Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS**. My server's got two **Ultra320 SCSI HDDs** but in the Ubuntu installation process, the OS fails to recognize them. I have tried to manually select `hpsa` and `cciss` drivers, but it did nothing. What do I need to do to make make the drives recognizable?

Comment: Have you considered using a supported operating system?

Comment: @Chopper3 No, why? xD ... Yes, I will try to download one of them. Now I'm googling but I can't find the list.

Comment: Cool, pretty sure you'll be ok with an RHEL variant (Centos etc.)

Comment: I have succeed with older Ubuntu version, it has been installed without a problem. I will add it as an answer soon. Thanks for your help, @Chopper3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you create a logical drive first in the RAID controller BIOS?

Hit `F8` during the Smart Array 5i RAID Controller BIOS screen. Create a logical drive.

After that is done, you should be able to see a disk through the [CCISS driver](http://cciss.sourceforge.net) in the Linux installer. No other action is needed.

Comment: Yes I did this before installing older version. So this is probably the solution :)